# Склоняется ли "сколько"?

Tags: склонение, числительные

Как правильно сказать:

> *На скольких человек заказывать пиццу*

или

> *На сколько человек заказывать пиццу*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Склоняется.

**Им.**  `сколько`

**Род.** `скольких`

**Дат.** `скольким`, `(по) скольку`

**Тв.**  `сколькими`

**Пр.**  `скольких`

**Вин. одуш.** `скольких`

**Вин. неодуш.** `сколько`

Местоимение `сколько` склоняется по типу прилагательных с основой на мягкий согласный. К особенностям склонения относится то, что в именительном и винительном падежах оно, подобно именам числительным, управляет падежом, т.е. требует после себя определенного падежа, а именно род. п. мн. ч., например:

> Сколько окон в доме?

Употребляясь в остальных падежах, это местоимение, как имена прилагательные, согласуется с существительным.

Взято [отсюда](http://spelling.siteedit.ru/skolko), там же есть и мнемоническое стихотворение для запоминания падежных форм этого слова и места ударения в них (ударение всегда на корне, не на окончании).

Comment: Значит ли это, что вариант *на сколько человек заказывать пиццу?* неверный?

Comment: Розенталь в "Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати" [пишет (§151, пункт 5)](http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/rozent1/03.php) (там почти в самом конце страницы), что "Из двух вариантов: встретить нескольких товарищей и встретить несколько товарищей — в настоящее время более употребителен второй (то же при словах сколько, столько)." - Однако я воспринимаю это только как тенденцию. Возможно, что в будущем она закрепится как норма, но пока что этого не произошло. Однако, это может быть оправданием и объяснением ваших сомнений.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the ending -их adds a meaning similar to the definite article in English. In your sentences it is meaningless, so I would always say

> На сколько человек заказывать пиццу?

But the phrase

> Я встретил нескольких товарищей.

would mean

> I encountered several of **the** comrades.

or

> I encountered certain comrades.

while

> Я встретил несколькo товарищей.

would mean

> I encountered a few comrades.

The -их implies an omitted clarifier:

> На скольких [из вас] накрывать стол?
>
> Я встретил нескольких [из них].

You cannot use the "сколько" with this clarifyer.